# Compactness Of Sets And Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I was studying compactness property and got stuck on a point. I first saw the definition of compactness as : A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X, d)$ is said to be compact if for any collection of open subsets of $X$ that cover $A$, there is a finite subcollection that covers $A$. Now I saw problems in which there was compact metric space, but how can compactness be defined for metric spaces as metric spaces are themselves full spaces and hence how a collection of open sets will cover them and relative to which spaces those sets will be open??

Comment: Does setting $X=A$ in your definition answer your question?

Comment: Yes that is fine but how open sets will cover $X$ as this space is itself a full space

Comment: @user771946 And is it inconceivable that the full support set $X$ of the space we *abusively* denote also by $X$ (ignoring the topology) be covered by a certain collection of its open subsets? Certainly the collection $\{X\}$ always achieves this and so will any other collection which includes this singleton! Such collections have the obvious property of including a *finite* subcover, namely $\{X\}$! What characterises a compact space is that *any* open cover -- out of the vast infinity it might possess -- necessarily includes a finite subcover.

Comment: That it covers X does not mean that it is strictly containing X. For example, the open intervals $(n-1, n+1)$ for all integers n cover $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Arctic Char Now Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $A \subset X$, then how the compactness Of the subspace $(A, d')$ will be defined and the sets that will cover $A$ will be open relative to $d$ or $d'$

Comment: The open sets in A are those of the form $U=A\cap V$, where $V$ is open in X

Answer (score 1):

It might be better not to start with a definition of **compact subsets** of a topological space but with a definition of **compact spaces**.

This by:

> If $(X,\tau)$ denotes a topological space then it is a compact topological space if any cover of $X$ by open sets contains a finite subcover.

Based on that you can secondly define the concept of compact subsets like this:

> If $(X,\tau)$ denotes a topological space then a set $A\subseteq X$ is a compact subset of the space if the subspace $(A,\tau')$ is a compact subspace.

Here $\tau'$ denotes the subspace topology on $A$ inherited from topological space $(X,\tau)$ and defined as $\tau':=\{A\cap U\mid U\in\tau\}$.

---

If you like then you can easily translate this to metric spaces.